# java.lang.Long cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, jsonp

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://gateway.ceylonlinux.com/hayleys2/services/getUserStokDetail?token=40da9b9ed74f672c3871d76a2c87857b&timestamp=0");
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
            JSONObject posts = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            JSONArray jArray = posts.getJSONArray("timestamp");
            Log.i("Tag", jArray.toString());
```

I tried above code to retrieve data from server but when i try that i get following error

```
12-06 11:12:27.539: W/System.err(4870): org.json.JSONException: Value 1386308549000 at timestamp of type java.lang.Long cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: `timestamp` is not any array. share the Json string

Comment: http://gateway.ceylonlinux.com/hayleys2/services/getUserStokDetail?token=40da9b9ed74f672c3871d76a2c87857b&timestamp=0

Answer (score 2):

`timestamp` is value instead of `JSONArray`.`stock` is JSONArray. get both value as:

```
 JSONArray jArray = posts.getJSONArray("stock"); /// get stock JSONArray
 Log.i("Tag", jArray.toString());

 long timestamp=posts.getLong("timestamp"); /// get timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
 JSONArray jArray = posts.getJSONArray("timestamp");
```

With this one :

```
 long mTimeStamp = posts.getLong("timestamp");
```

Because in your `JSON String` `timestamp` is an `long value` not an `array`

In your `JSON String` `stock` is an `array` so you can get `stock` by using this

```
 JSONArray jArray = posts.getJSONArray("stock");
```

Answer (score 0):

check your Json string whether it has jsonArray named timestamp or it  have only  a long variable named timestamp. you can check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for json structure also.